# Unable to make POST call via tinyOauth 1.0a in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, oauth, restsharp

I am trying to make a **post call** via **TinyOauth 1.0a .NET package** but I am always getting **the invalid_oauth signature**. I am using **RestClient(RestSharp)** for Post Call Although it is working fine in postman.
Can anyone help me how to make post call via restsharp client and tinyOauth in .NET?

```
Request:
{
  "cardNumber": "199990713879999",
  "storeId": "12",
  "pin": "458920"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You need to add RestSharp and TinyOauth1.0 in your project from nuget packet manager for the call

```
public async Task<string> httpCalls(string url, bool isGet, string data)
        {
            String responseJson = String.Empty;
            AccessTokenInfo accessTokenInfo = await OAuth();
            TinyOAuth tinyOAuth = new TinyOAuth(oauthConfig());
            RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
            RestRequest request;

            if (isGet == true)
            {
                request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", tinyOAuth.GetAuthorizationHeader(accessTokenInfo.AccessToken, accessTokenInfo.AccessTokenSecret, url, HttpMethod.Get).ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", tinyOAuth.GetAuthorizationHeader(accessTokenInfo.AccessToken, accessTokenInfo.AccessTokenSecret, url, HttpMethod.Post).ToString());
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddParameter("undefined", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            }
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return response.Content;
        }
```